# Custom module not indexing in search

Tags: search

I'm using drupal search module to search/find/filter content in my **CUSTOM MODULE** and it's not returning any results when I search for a word listed in content of my custom module content type. It return results only when i search for a users and others content type.

Any body knows what can i do to fix this? Do I have to implement any hook to index the content of my custom module?

**PS:**

1) My **custom module** it's based in the **drupal core blog** module

2) I was using **Custom Search** module, but i've disabled it

3) I've tried the search api module and views exposed filter (Search Terms) and nothing

Thank you

Comment: Is your site indexed?

Comment: Duplicate of http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/57275/site-search-not-picking-up-all-pages

Comment: yes, 100% indexed. I've runned the cron and it's all indexed

Comment: Does a direct link to http://www.example.com/search/node/foo bring up a 404 or the no results page?

Comment: @MPD when i search for "FOO" I get the path mysite.com/search/node/FOO and "Your search yielded no results". I still don't know why this is occurring. I'm trying to fix this within 2 days and nothing

Comment: When I search for something in a general node (basic pages), it works. But it don't show results from other content types with custom fields. Is this happening because the custom fields (CCK)? Thank you

Comment: @user19627  See my answer.  I suspect the second paragraph is the problem.

Comment: Please update to more meaningful topic. :)

Comment: Thank you for your help guys. I've tried your tips, but still not working. I've updated my question to provide more information. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

This is a shot in the dark, but I would do the following.  This assumes you are on Drupal 7.

On, admin/structure/types/manage/page/display, open **Custom Settings** and select **Search Index**.  Save.  Then click on the **Search Index** tab and configure the view mode for all of the fields that you want to search in.

On admin/config/search/settings, make sure that you have **Node** selected.

On admin/config/search/custom_search/content, double check that you have selected the content types that you want to search (or leave that fieldset empty).  Also check that you aren't excluding any types that you actually want to search.

If your site isn't that big, I would dump the search index and rebuild id.  I normally do this from drush:

```
drush search-reindex
drush search-index
```

Then, open your MySQL tool of choice, and look for a few keywords that you know you should have hits on:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    search_index
WHERE
    word = 'foo'
```

If all of that works, then you shouldbe getting search results.  If not, you need to find what is interfering with the indexing, which could be specific to your system.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but did not work... I've updated my question to provide more information. Thank you in advance